# async with lock - возможности

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Не совсем разобрался с конструкций
`async with lock`: для python.

Мне нужно сделать так что одномоментно выполнялась только одна функция для работы с базой данных. То есть было монополное обращение к базе. Функций для работ с базой несколько.

asyncio `scheduler.add_job()` запускает по расписанию N функций `doWork1, doWork2, doWork3` и т.д., которые в свою очередь вызывают функции для работы с базой данных (`query1, query2, query3`). Вопрос может ли async with lock помочь с ограничением на одномоментное исполнение только одной функции для работы с базой данных? Если да, то как? По идее для этой задачи нужно использовать очередь, но возможно и `lock` может помочь упростить реализацию.

https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-asyncio-python/primitivy-sinhronizatsii-zadach-asyncio/

---

Ниже приведен рабочий псевдокод решаемой задачи.
Требуется чтобы в единицу времени работал только один блок выделенный `async with lock:` в независимости от того какая функция выполняется `strategyBuy` или `strategySell` и сколько экземпляров этих функций запущенно. Все остальные блоки должны "ставиться в очередь" и обрабатываться последовательно. Вопрос может ли  `async with lock:` помочь с данной реализацией для конкретной задачи?
В текущем результате примера видно что записи `Bought2.` появились несколько раз и этого говорит о том, что участок кода `async with lock:` для  `strategyBuy` выполнялался параллельно, что недопустимо. По идее `Bought2.` отображается только в случае если в базе данных нет записей или нет записей с `side: 'buy'` и `parent_id is null`. При первом запуске эти оба условия True (только для первой записи).

```
import random
import asyncio
import aiosqlite as aiosql
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
import uuid
import numpy as np

myState = 0


async def dbConnect():

    sqlConn = await aiosql.connect('test.db')

    await sqlConn.execute("""
                        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl(
                            id TEXT NOT NULL,
                            side TEXT NOT NULL,
                            price NUMERIC NOT NULL,
                            parent_id TEXT NULL,
                            buy_ids TEXT NULL
                        )""")

    return sqlConn


async def check():
    return (random.uniform(0, 1) < 0.05)


async def fetchPrice():
    return random.uniform(0, 1)


async def sell():
    pass


async def getOpenBuyOrders(sqlConn):

    cursor = await sqlConn.execute(
        """SELECT id, price, parent_id
            FROM tbl
            WHERE side='buy'
                AND parent_id IS NULL""")

    return await cursor.fetchall()


async def saveBuyOrder(sqlConn, price):
    buyId = uuid.uuid1()
    await sqlConn.execute(f"INSERT INTO tbl(id, price, side) VALUES (?, ?, 'buy')", (buyId.hex, price))
    await sqlConn.commit()


async def saveSellOrder(sqlConn, price, buyIDs):
    sellId = uuid.uuid1()
    await sqlConn.execute(f"INSERT INTO tbl (id, price, buy_ids, side) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 'sell')", (sellId.hex, price, str(buyIDs)))

    buyIDString = ','.join(['?']*len(buyIDs))
    await sqlConn.execute(f"UPDATE tbl SET parent_id = ? WHERE  id in (?)", (sellId.hex, buyIDString))

    await sqlConn.commit()


async def strategyBuy(sqlConn, i):

    lock = asyncio.Lock()

    if(await check()):

        currentPrice = await fetchPrice()

        async with lock:
            global myState
            myState = myState + 1
            openBuyOrders = await getOpenBuyOrders(sqlConn)
            if(openBuyOrders):
                avgPrice = np.mean([openBuyOrder[1]
                                    for openBuyOrder in openBuyOrders])

                if(avgPrice > (currentPrice * 1.05)):
                    await saveBuyOrder(sqlConn, currentPrice)
                    print(f"Bought1. Task: {i}, myState:{myState}")

            else:
                await saveBuyOrder(sqlConn, currentPrice)
                print(f"Bought2. Task: {i}, myState:{myState}")

    return None


async def strategySell(sqlConn, i):

    lock = asyncio.Lock()

    if(await check()):

        currentPrice = await fetchPrice()

        async with lock:
            global myState
            myState = myState + 1
            openBuyOrders = await getOpenBuyOrders(sqlConn)

            if(openBuyOrders):
                avgPrice = np.mean([openBuyOrder[1]
                                    for openBuyOrder in openBuyOrders])

                if((avgPrice * 1.05) < currentPrice):

                    buyIDs = [openBuyOrder[0]
                              for openBuyOrder in openBuyOrders]
                    await saveSellOrder(sqlConn, currentPrice, buyIDs)
                    print(f"Sold. Task: {i}, myState:{myState}")

    return None


async def main():

    sqlConn = await dbConnect()

    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()

    for i in range(100):
        scheduler.add_job(strategyBuy, 'interval', seconds=10, args=[sqlConn, i],
                          start_date='2000-01-01 00:00:00', timezone='UTC')

        scheduler.add_job(strategySell, 'interval', seconds=10, args=[sqlConn, i],
                          start_date='2000-01-01 00:00:00', timezone='UTC')

    scheduler.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(main())
    loop.run_forever()
```

Результат

```
Bought2. Task: 55, myState:15
Bought2. Task: 13, myState:15
Bought2. Task: 80, myState:15
Bought2. Task: 57, myState:15
Bought2. Task: 24, myState:15
Bought2. Task: 44, myState:15
Bought2. Task: 18, myState:15
Bought2. Task: 7, myState:15
Bought2. Task: 49, myState:15
Bought1. Task: 86, myState:19
Bought1. Task: 97, myState:19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну видимо `lock = asyncio.Lock()` надо вынести в блок `if __name__ == "__main__":` и все получится

Comment: Вопрос реализованная схема на сколько правильная и оптимальная с точки зрения архитектурной реализации и производительности ?

Answer (score 2):

а в чем проблема проверить на подобном примере? видно, что сами функции выполняются параллельно, кроме их with lock блоков

```
import asyncio

async def t1():
    print('t1 start')
    # await lock.acquire()
    async with lock:
        print('t1 lock')
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print('t1 sleep')
        # lock.release()
        print('t1 release')

async def t2():
    print('t2 start')
    async with lock:
        # await lock.acquire()
        print('t2 lock')
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print('t2 sleep')
        # lock.release()
        print('t2 release')

lock = asyncio.Lock()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([loop.create_task(t1()), loop.create_task(t2()),]))
loop.close()
```

out

```
t1 start
t1 lock
t2 start
t1 sleep
t1 release
t2 lock
t2 sleep
t2 release
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо  [vadim vaduxa](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/208915/vadim-vaduxa)
Выкладываю рабочий вариант скрипта

```
import random
import asyncio
import aiosqlite as aiosql
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
import uuid
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime


async def dbConnect():

    sqlConn = await aiosql.connect('test.db')

    await sqlConn.execute("""
                        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl(
                            id TEXT NOT NULL,
                            side TEXT NOT NULL,
                            price NUMERIC NOT NULL,
                            parent_id TEXT NULL,
                            buy_ids TEXT NULL
                        )""")

    return sqlConn


async def check():
    return (random.uniform(0, 1) < 0.05)


async def fetchPrice():
    return random.uniform(0, 1)


async def sell():
    pass


async def getOpenBuyOrders(sqlConn):

    cursor = await sqlConn.execute(
        """SELECT id, price, parent_id
            FROM tbl
            WHERE side='buy'
                AND parent_id IS NULL""")

    return await cursor.fetchall()


async def saveBuyOrder(sqlConn, price):
    buyId = uuid.uuid1()
    await sqlConn.execute(f"INSERT INTO tbl(id, price, side) VALUES (?, ?, 'buy')", (buyId.hex, price))
    await sqlConn.commit()


async def saveSellOrder(sqlConn, price, buyIDs):
    sellId = uuid.uuid1()
    await sqlConn.execute(f"INSERT INTO tbl (id, price, buy_ids, side) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 'sell')", (sellId.hex, price, str(buyIDs)))

    buyIDString = "'"+("','".join(buyIDs*len(buyIDs)))+"'"
    await sqlConn.execute(f"UPDATE tbl SET parent_id = '{sellId.hex}' WHERE  id in ({buyIDString})")

    await sqlConn.commit()


async def strategyBuy(sqlConn, i):

    if(await check()):

        currentPrice = await fetchPrice()

        if not lock.locked():
            async with lock:
                global myState
                openBuyOrders = await getOpenBuyOrders(sqlConn)
                if(openBuyOrders):
                    avgPrice = np.mean([openBuyOrder[1]
                                        for openBuyOrder in openBuyOrders])

                    if(avgPrice > (currentPrice * 1.05)):
                        await saveBuyOrder(sqlConn, currentPrice)
                        myState = myState + 1
                        print(
                            f"{datetime.now()} Bought1. Task: {i}, myState:{myState}")

                else:
                    await saveBuyOrder(sqlConn, currentPrice)

                    myState = myState + 1
                    print(f"{datetime.now()} Bought2. Task: {i}, myState:{myState}")

    return None


async def strategySell(sqlConn, i):

    if(await check()):

        currentPrice = await fetchPrice()

        if not lock.locked():
            async with lock:

                openBuyOrders = await getOpenBuyOrders(sqlConn)

                if(openBuyOrders):
                    avgPrice = np.mean([openBuyOrder[1]
                                        for openBuyOrder in openBuyOrders])

                    if((avgPrice * 1.05) < currentPrice):

                        buyIDs = [openBuyOrder[0]
                                  for openBuyOrder in openBuyOrders]
                        await saveSellOrder(sqlConn, currentPrice, buyIDs)
                        global myState
                        myState = myState + 1
                        print(
                            f"{datetime.now()} Sold. Task: {i}, myState:{myState}")

    return None


async def main():

    sqlConn = await dbConnect()

    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()

    for i in range(1000):
        scheduler.add_job(strategyBuy, 'interval', seconds=20, args=[sqlConn, i],
                          start_date='2000-01-01 00:00:00', timezone='UTC')

        scheduler.add_job(strategySell, 'interval', seconds=20, args=[sqlConn, i],
                          start_date='2000-01-01 00:00:00', timezone='UTC')

    scheduler.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lock = asyncio.Lock()
    myState = 0
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(main())
    loop.run_forever()
```